# Using Selenium to download PDFs from relative links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Chrome WebDriver to try to capture and download a bunch of files on a website for my community organization. The website has about 2,700 PDF files uploaded over many years in various places.  They are linked to from various pages on the site, e.g. here is an example

[image: Sample Link to PDF]

Note a couple of things:

- The URL to the file is always relative.
- If I try to use the full URL in a Selenium script, e.g.

`driver.get("https://engage.goenumerate.com/s/bpha/files/1118/dyn291835/Bill%20Point%20Water%20System%20Replacement%20Drawings.pdf")`

I get a 404 from the website.  It appears they have in some server-side filter blocked direct download of the URLs.

If in an interactive session, I click on the link it opens the PDF in a new tab (`target=_blank`).

I would like to capture the contents of the PDF in my Python code and save the PDF to a local directory, and then move on to the next file.

I have a CSV list of these:

[image: CSV of files to download]

I can write Selenium code to find and click the links on the pages with the links to the files, but that will just open the PDFs in the Chrome WebDriver browser - not give me the PDF.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: http://www.billpointhoa.com — there are some public facing documents under the Resources menu.  Many hundreds more behind login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package with a context manager to save the files.

Also, `selenium` is not necessary to extract the URLs from the page you provided. This snipped will download all the PDF files in `https://engage.goenumerate.com/s/bpha/publicresources.php`.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib.parse

res: bytes = requests.get("https://engage.goenumerate.com/s/bpha/publicresources.php").content
tree: html.HtmlElement = html.fromstring(res)
for i in tree.xpath(".//a[contains(@href, '.pdf') or contains(@href, '.PDF') ]/@href"):
    filename: str = urllib.parse.unquote(i.split("/")[-1])
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        pdf_content: bytes = requests.get("https://engage.goenumerate.com/s/bpha/" + i).content
        f.write(pdf_content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to get the links and then requests to download the files.

```
import requests

url = "https://engage.goenumerate.com/s/bpha/files/1118/dyn3127/Articles_of_Incorporation.pdf"

pdf = requests.get(url=url).content
with open("cool.pdf", 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(pdf)
```

You may need to include headers in your requests.

Comment: This works great - TYVM.